# How to fix my login model in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3, login-script

When I insert data with encrypted password by my registration controller, this data was inserted. But when I login it says incorrect password.
My registration controller code is:

```
$encrypted_password = $this->encryption->encrypt($this->input- >post('user_password'));
```

Login Model code is:

```
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
function can_login($email, $password)
{
    $this->db->where('User_email' , $email);
    $query  = $this->db->get('tbl_user');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            if($row->is_email_verified == 'yes'){
                $store_password = $this->encryption->decrypt($row->User_password);
                if($password == $store_password)
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('id', $row->id);
                }
                else
                {
                    return 'Worng Password';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 'First verified your email address';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
      return 'Wrong Email Address';  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you saving encrypted password in db?

Comment: You should never use encryption that can be reversed for your passwords. If someone breaks into your server, encrypted passwords could easily be read. You must use [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this one help you....

```
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
function can_login($email, $password)
{
    $this->db->where('User_email' , $email);
    $query  = $this->db->get('tbl_user');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            if($row->is_email_verified == 'yes'){
                $store_password = $row->User_password;
                $current_password = $this->encryption->encrypt($password);
                if($current_password == $store_password)
                {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('id', $row->id);
                }
                else
                {
                    return 'Worng Password';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 'First verified your email address';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
      return 'Wrong Email Address';  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the problem?

Comment: yeah,  encrypt new password  without de -encrypt old password. So that new password encrypt == old also encrypt.